# In flutter, How to add tflite as a dependency in pubspec.yaml ?file?

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow-lite

I am little bit confused with this. Now I have `.tflite` and `label.txt` but right now I want to access **TensorFlow** lite using **Flutter Plugin**. 
In here I am confused with adding  `tflite` as a dependency in  `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **tflite: ^1.0.4** below **cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV9lo.png]

1. make a new directory in your project called **assets**.
2. copy your file in **assets** folder.
3. add asset below **uses-material-design:true** to your **pubspec.yaml**
   for eg. 

   assets:

    - assets/label.txt
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjOIP.png]

Answer (score 0):

You need provide in assets section:

```
  assets:
    - path/to/your/file
```

To access your asset:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('path/to/your/file');
}
```

[Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

Pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  camera: 0.4.0

  tflite: 1.0.4
```

And in Asset folder is your `.tflite` files which, can be generated your own training, labels, and inferences or from manual copying from a GitHub file as they are specifically generated by TensorFlow image data. [See here for more details](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/overview)

Assets folder

[image: tflite]